# ReturnUrl not working and is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET MVC Core web app with `Individual User Account` authentication, the `returnurl` in the default login() get and post action methods (shown below) is always null. I verified it by placing a breakpoint after the line `ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;`. When I login to the app I see at the breakpoint that returnUrl is always null. Why is that even though I can see that the corresponding form tag has `asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]"` attribute value defined? I see the same null behavior in other action methods where I'm using returnUrl and making sure that the corresponding form tags of these action methods have `asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]"` attribute defined.

**AccountCountroller**:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

**Snapshot of login.cshtml view**:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
.....//rest of the html removed for brevity
.....
</form>
```

Comment: When you go to `Login` action method, Are you passing in the `returnUrl` param value as well  in the querystring ?

Comment: @Shyju Thank you for trying to help. The action methods shown above are by default (created when you select `Individual Users Account` option at the time of project creation). I assumed `asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]"` attribute setting in the form tag would do it itself. But it seems I'm wrongly assuming this. So, how do I pass the `returnurl` param?

Comment: Just to be sure - you know that the 'returnUrl' will only have value if you are trying to access a controller that is decorated by [Authorize] attribute and bounced back to login, right?

Comment: @ZivWeissman Thank you for pointing that out. Yes, my default AccountController does have the Authorize attribute by default. After reading your comment, I've modified the `AccountController` section in my post.

Comment: In addition to what others have pointed out, the top action method will only respond to HTTP get. The bottom one will only respond to HTTP post, which is the only one that will look at form tags. With HTTP get, you can only use the URL, headers or cookies to pass information such as returnUrl, form tags are not relevant with HTTP get.